# String function (str_replace) in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a PHP function as follows:

```
<?php
function fixEncoding ($str){
    $searchVal = array("?", "=", ":", ";", "#", "+", "%", "&" );
    $replaceVal = array("%3F", "%3D", "%3A", "%3B", "%23", "%2B", "%25", "%26" );
    return str_replace($searchVal, $replaceVal, $str);  
}
$test_string = "www.joensuu.fi/documents/144181/2569169/Joensuun-Areena.jpg/69933c17-e619-7d05-a64a-94bfbb533da9?t=1550323540726";
$result = fixEncoding($test_string);
echo $result;
?>
```

Output:

```
www.joensuu.fi/documents/144181/2569169/Joensuun-Areena.jpg/69933c17-e619-7d05-a64a-94bfbb533da9%253Ft%253D1550323540726
```

This function successfully replaces '?' and '=' characters, however, it later replaces their '%' character with '%25' also, which does not make it expected output.
Any suggestions, for how I can handle this.

Comment: Move %25 to be the first element in the array would likely do it. I can't help but think that `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` might be easier

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thanks, it do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put % first in your array like

```
$searchVal = array("%", "?", "=", ":", ";", "#", "+", "&" );
```

but you should also consider using JureW's answer

Answer (score 0):

If I uderstand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
www.joensuu.fi%2Fdocuments%2F144181%2F2569169%2FJoensuun-Areena.jpg%2F69933c17-e619-7d05-a64a-94bfbb533da9%3Ft%3D1550323540726
```

If so, no need to build your own function:

```
print_r(urlencode($test_string)); // outputs same as example above
```

PHP has built in function for encoding/decoding url's, so lets not reinvent the wheel and use those :)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
function fixEncoding ($str){
    return urlencode($str);
}

$test_string = "test???";
$result = fixEncoding($test_string);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Why creating a function that returns a result of PHP built in function?